# Split Paragraphs and Create new Dataframe Columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with Project | Summary and I am looking to split Summary into separate columns for each sub-section mentioned in the Summary. I am looking to parse this out to make 1 column per section, but am running into issues where there are differing total sections.

I used the following code to just grab 'Next Steps' but it also pulls in the additional columns where they appear. I also could only figure out how to get it for the first row.

Any ideas on how to make this more streamlined?

```
result = df['Summary'][0]
step_loc = result.find('Next steps')
step = result['current_status']['text'][step_loc+10:]
step = step.replace('\n', '').lstrip(' ')
```

ex.

```
Summary
    this is random long text


What we've accomplished

What's blocked

Next steps
```

and some of the rows have more sections:

```
Summary
nothing

What we've accomplished
none

What's blocked
xyz 

Next steps

Who's Involved

Weekly Fun Fact
```

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly fewer lines:

```
step = df['Summary'][0]['current_status']['text'][df['Summary'][0].find('Next steps')+10:].replace('\n', '').lstrip(' ')
```

Comment: This got me the Next Steps piece, but doesn't get me the rest of the data... any ideas how to expand this?

Comment: You'll need to provide details as to how the data is organized (i.e. not a description, but an example w/ explanation) and just what you want from it.